# Trying to save and check if a file was saved in the internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a txt file in internal storage.
When I execute the action and call the function responsible for creating the file, no error occurs. However when I check if the file was actually created in the /data/data/ folder, I can not find the folder with the name of my package.

Where is the error?

Ps.: I already saw several links from here on the subject, but in all cases the same case.

```
public void criarArq(Context mcoContext,String sFileName, String sBody){
    File file = new File(mcoContext.getFilesDir(),"mydir");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
    }

    try{
        File gpxfile = new File(file, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

And I call the function this way...

```
criarArq(getApplicationContext(), arqNome, "teste");
```

Thank you for all help!

--- Update ---

This is my code now:

```
try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append("teste");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(InfoEntregasActivity.this, "created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Don't eat the exception, do something with it, e.g.
            Log.e("criarArq", e.toString()); //this will give you your error in the log cat
            Toast.makeText(InfoEntregasActivity.this, e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            throw new RuntimeException(e); //this will bomb your program out for when the error is unrecoverable
        }
```

**I try with and without the Toast (same result), but with Toast I always get "created" msg.**

Comment: You shouldn't swallow exceptions. `}catch (Exception e){}` Log the error, recover, or crash when appropriate.

Comment: You do not see an error when you create the file because your `try...catch` ignores it. You should change the `criarArq()` method to declare the exceptions that can be thrown and then the UI code will have a `try...catch` which decides what to do when an error occurs.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider and Code-Apprentice, I already fixed that, but still in the same situation. Thanks for help.

Comment: "I can not find the folder with the name of my package." what makes you think it would be in a folder with the name of you package?

Comment: Based on your edit, the file is successfully created. We don't have access to your file system, but I'd be willing to bet it's there somewhere.

Comment: Oh I see why, but I think mcoContext.getFilesDir() may not always include the package name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775949/what-path-does-getapplicationcontext-getfilesdir-return

Comment: You all are right! File created. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...no error occurs

You're eating any potential exception, so I wouldn't be so sure.

```
public void criarArq(Context mcoContext,  String fileName, String body) {
    File file = new File(mcoContext.getFilesDir(),"mydir");
    file.mkdirs(); //no need to check exists with mkdirs

    File gpxfile = new File(file, fileName);
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(body);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Don't eat the exception, do something with it, e.g.
        Log.e("criarArq", e.toString()); //this will give you your error in the log cat
        throw new RuntimeException(e); //this will bomb your program out for when the error is unrecoverable
    }
}
```

Additional tips, `mkdirs` makes multiple levels and does the `exists` check for you.

Do not use prefixes relating the to type, e.g. `s...` it's quite old fashioned, pre-dating modern IDEs.

## To see where your file is going

```
Log.d("criarArq", gpxfile.toString());
```

Comment: I'm still learning. Thank you for your help!
I understood what you said and adjusted everything. However, the same situation continues: no mistake happens.
I add toast messages to test and nothing happens.

I update the question with the new function.

Comment: We're all still learning! Don't trust anyone who says they're not :D

Comment: With the Log.d(...) I could see the file path. Thank you! I don't have enough reputation to vote =/, but your answer was a solution!

Comment: Out of interest, where was the file going?

Comment: It was on /data/data/[pkgname] but I could not see because my phone doesn't have root