# How do I access the textfile I created?

Tags: java, android, text-files

```
 file = new File(getFilesDir(), "data.txt");
 try {
   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
   fos.write(data.getBytes());
   fos.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Is there a way to export this file so I can have access to it? I don't have a SD-card available btw.

Comment: It should be somewhere if you created it am I right

Comment: You want to read the contents of the file?

Comment: @Vusal I want to export it outside the phone? How do I access it?

Comment: @JoSem It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you have no SD card, you can either write to the local storage (which isn't what you want) or use some cloud- or network service. For the latter, I am sure there are some tutorials covering e.g. google drive, dropbox, owncloud,...

Comment: @Turing85 How is it unclear? lol. I want to export the file to my computer. Right now I can only read from it within the app.

Comment: Just now did you actually mention that you wish to export the file to your PC (that was unclear up until now). You did not specify HOW you want to transfer the file. Do you want to send it via BlueTooth? USB Connection? A network share?

Comment: Sorry, the thing is that I have a txtfile that collects sensordata, and I need that textfile to format it. Right now I have no sd-card on my phone, and I've tried internal storage, but then I can't find the textfile. What are my options? thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/", "yourFile.extension");
```

This is for downloads directory.

Then to open your file

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
Intent j = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose an application to open with:");
startActivity(j);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have managed to fix it, I was confused by the external/internal storage.

Comment: Thats good :) Please mark this as answer if it helped you. It will give me reputation :p

Comment: Sure, why not, there you go! :)

Comment: Thanks bro :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your application path use `getFilesDir()` which will give you path `/data/data/<your package>/files`

So, you can find your file using android file manager in above mentioned directory.

From [getFilesDir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230629/getfilesdir-vs-environment-getdatadirectory)

Comment: Yes, but I can't find the folder on my phone for some reason. I just want the textfile exported so I can format it. Is that possible?

Comment: Try to use `getExternalFilesDir()` method. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052803/4213803)

Comment: Isn't external storage explicitly for SD-memory? I don't have a sd-card